# Snippet para deploy laravel vía termius

Tags: laravel, git, deployment

Estoy generando un snippet para hacer deploy en mi aplicacion api de laravel. Con la finalidad de que cuando ya funcione correctamente utilizarlo con alguno de los hooks de git.
Los pasos del snippet son los siguientes:

```
sudo su
sudo systemctl stop php8.1-fpm
cd /var/www/api-laravel
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:cache
sudo systemctl start php8.1-fpm
```

el problema que tengo en este momento, es que al hacer el pull (paso N°5), me solicita una clave.
¿como puedo hacer para que esta clave/token, se coloque de forma automatica, para que realice el pull sin una interaccion?

No he querido hacer una clave ssh con mi cuenta, debido a que hay otros devs que tambien podrian requerir hacer deploys entonces, no puede quedar amarrado a mi usuario de git.
desconozco si existe o se pueden crear claves exclusivamente para deploys.

En fin, espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Eso se puede hacer sin muchos problemas usando un certificado ssh. Generas un certificado _sin clave_. Pones en el hosting la llave pública y configuras git para que use la llave privada (y el URL del repositorio remoto debe usar ssh en vez de https) y con eso no tendrías necesidad de proveer ninguna clave al momento de hacer un pull/fetch/push. https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: Hola @eftshift0
con el certificado ssh, quedaría vinculado a mi cuenta de gihub. Etonces,, si otro desarrollador del equipo, quiere hacer un deploy, va a hacerlo con mis datos, O cada persona podria crear una ssh en el servidor?. Disculpa , no soy tan pro en git.

Comment: Esas preguntas que estas haciendo abren un sin fin de posibilidades solo al tratar de _definir_ lo que quieres decir _específicamente _ con cada una de ellas. Solo estoy tratando de resolver *puntualmente* el punto con respecto all paso 5 de la pregunta original. Si el URL del remoto está usando ssh como transporte, tienes la posibilidad de usar certificados _sin firma_ para que el pull se pueda hacer sin necesidad de proveer una clave de forma interactiva (de tal forma que lo puedes usar en un script o en un hook sin intervención de usuario).